# how to create html table rows from multiple arrays of data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to display data coming in from a Firebase project.

After retrieving the data as a snapshot, I am trying to pull it into a simple HTML table.

I have taken the initial data and extracted 3 arrays just of the values I need to display, e.g.

```
["title1", "title2", "title3"]
["author1", "author2", "author3"]
["1992", "1994", "1987"]
```

I have a basic javascript function that creates the number of table columns based on the number of arrays I pull in. What I am struggling with is how to build each row in javascript, being that each row should be:

```
title1 - author1 - year1
title2 - author2 - year2
```

etc.

Comment: Please post the JavaScript you tried

Comment: Chances are you already have rows in the initial data. Show how you generate those arrays also and what stored data looks like

Comment: It should be a trivial `for()` loop. Use the index to access corresponding elements of each array and put them in the cells of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you have array containing information like this:

```
["title1", "title2", "title3"]
["author1", "author2", "author3"]
["1992", "1994", "1987"]
```

This means that `array[0][0]` -> refers to `"title1"`, `array[1][0] -> "author1"` and `array[2][0] -> "1992"`

In this case we have three separate arrays combined into one. Let's assume that the `length` of this arrays are same `->` in this case `3`:

```
function buildData()
{
   var array = [["title1", "title2", "title3"], 
                 ["author1", "author2", "author3"], 
                  ["1992", "1994", "1987"]];
    var table = document.createElement("table");
        var trOne = document.createElement("tr"); 
            var thOne = document.createElement("th"); 
                thOne.innerHTML = "Title";
            var thTwo = document.createElement("th"); 
                thTwo.innerHTML = "Author";
            var thThree = document.createElement("th"); 
                thThree.innerHTML = "Year";
            trOne.appendChild(thOne); trOne.appendChild(thTwo); 
            trOne.appendChild(thThree);
         table.appendChild(trOne);
     //We created header row and now we will create rows from your array
     for(var i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) 
     {
         var trTwo = document.createElement("tr"); 
             var tdOne = document.createElement("td"); 
                 tdOne.innerHTML = array[0][i]; //titles
             var tdTwo = document.createElement("td"); 
                 tdTwo.innerHTML = array[1][i]; //authors
             var tdThree = document.createElement("td"); 
                 tdThree.innerHTML = array[2][i]; //years
             trTwo.appendChild(tdOne); trTwo.appendChild(tdTwo); 
             trTwo.appendChild(tdThree);
          table.appendChild(trTwo);
     }
     document.body.appendChild(table);
}
```

```html
<script>
function buildData()
{
   var array = [["title1", "title2", "title3"], 
                 ["author1", "author2", "author3"], 
                  ["1992", "1994", "1987"]];
    var table = document.createElement("table");
        var trOne = document.createElement("tr"); 
            var thOne = document.createElement("th"); 
                thOne.innerHTML = "Title";
            var thTwo = document.createElement("th"); 
                thTwo.innerHTML = "Author";
            var thThree = document.createElement("th"); 
                thThree.innerHTML = "Year";
            trOne.appendChild(thOne); trOne.appendChild(thTwo); 
            trOne.appendChild(thThree);
         table.appendChild(trOne);
     //We created header row and now we will create rows from your array
     for(var i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) 
     {
         var trTwo = document.createElement("tr"); 
             var tdOne = document.createElement("td"); 
                 tdOne.innerHTML = array[0][i]; //titles
             var tdTwo = document.createElement("td"); 
                 tdTwo.innerHTML = array[1][i]; //authors
             var tdThree = document.createElement("td"); 
                 tdThree.innerHTML = array[2][i]; //years
             trTwo.appendChild(tdOne); trTwo.appendChild(tdTwo); 
             trTwo.appendChild(tdThree);
          table.appendChild(trTwo);
     }
     document.body.appendChild(table);
}

</script>
<body onload='buildData();'>

</body>
```

Comment: I did, thanks. I went with something similar, but in looking at constructing the array of arrays realized that it would be better to digest the JSON from Firebase more directly so I now just iterate through the Firebase object after turning it into an array of objects, using `for (entry of data) { //build table }

Comment: @ScottKipp If it helped you can "Upvote" my comment. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A simple row Generator:

```
function rowInstance(rowData) {
    var row = elementInstance("TR");

    var len = rowData.length;
    for(var c = 0; c < len; c++) {
        var cell = cellInstance(rowData[c]);

        row.appendChild(cell);
    }

    return row;
}

function cellInstance(cellData) {
    var cell = elementInstance("TD");
    cell.innerText = cellData;

    return cell;
}

function elementInstance(tagName) {
    return document.createElement(tagName);
}
```

Pass an array to rowInstance(..) and it will create and fill a row.

Just append it to whatever table you like:

```
var table = document.querySelector("#myTable");
table.appendChild(rowInstance([0, "text", 9]));
```

To loop your specific data:

```
var titles = ["title1", "title2", "title3"];
var authors = ["author1", "author2", "author3"];
var years = ["1992", "1994", "1987"];

var table = document.querySelector("#myTable");

var len = titles.length;
for(var c = 0; c < len; c++) {
    table.appendChild(rowInstance([ titles[c], authors[c], years[c] ]));
}
```